# Getting Network Adapter Name even when adapter is disabled

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming

I've searched a lot but couldn't find the very same problem. So here it is:

When you open the menu with the Network Adapters in Windows, you see names like "Wifi 1". With `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` I only get information about the activated adapters but I need the disabled ones as well.

I can get the complete list of network devices via setupApi.dll and I can read all other data from the registry afterwards because I know the hardware ID. But where do those names come from and what is the best way to read them?

Any native c++ Windows solution that must be marshalled is fine. We just don't want to use WMI because it can be very slow.